# Why does this method not give the right multiples of 0.25 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, math

I am trying to get the multiples of 0.25 but i  am getting the wrong output. What am i doing wrong?

```js
let arr1 = []
for (let i = 0.25; i <= 4.25; i++) {
  //console.log(change)
  if (i > 3) {
    continue;
  }
  i % 0.25 == 0 ? arr1.push(i) : 'cancl'
  console.log(arr1) // i get [0.25, 1.25, 2.25] instead of [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, ...]
}
```

How can i get the write answer/multiples?

Comment: Because `i++` increment `i` by 1, that's why. You want to increment it by 0.25, `i = i + 0.25` or `i += 0.25`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because `i++` increments `i` by 1. Increment `i` by `0.25` instead:

```js
const arr1 = []
for (let i = .250; i <= 4.25; i += 0.25) {
  arr1.push(i)
}

console.log(arr1)
```

Comment: Remove `if (i > 3) {
    continue;
  }`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple flaw in the code is that it is getting incremented by 1.

The condition should be i = i+ .25

Checkout the code below

```js
let arr1 = []
for (let i = 0.25; i <= 4.25; i=i+.25) {
  //console.log(change)
  if (i > 3) {
    continue;
  }
  i % 0.25 == 0 ? arr1.push(i) : 'cancl'
   // i get [0.25, 1.25, 2.25] instead of [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, ...]
}

console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Because using i++, you will get i + 1 after iterating

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).